# Progess bar not shown on Drawer Layout

Tags: android, progress-bar, navigation-drawer, drawable

I can't find Progress bar in the Drawer layout. Change the position but not visible. I need the layout to be Drawer Layout only and can't be changed.
Help with some changes needed to make the progress bar visible.
The Progress bar must be visible to the user while webview is loading.

Below is my XML file for the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/webPBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:indeterminate="false" />



    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Everything that is not the drawer – the `<NavigationView>`, in this case – all needs to inside one `ViewGroup` listed before the `<NavigationView>`. That is, you need to somehow combine the `<LinearLayout>`, `<ProgressBar>`, and `<SwipeRefreshLayout>` into one, and put it where the `<LinearLayout>` is now.

Comment: Thanks, can u also help me how to enable scroll action to the navigation menu

Comment: A `DrawerLayout` should normally have only two direct children – the main content, and the drawer. Any child that is not a drawer is laid out to fill the `DrawerLayout`. You currently have three children that are not the drawer – the `<LinearLayout>`, the `<ProgressBar>`, and the `<SwipeRefreshLayout>`. Those are all stacked on top of each other, with the `<SwipeRefreshLayout>` being on top, and hiding the others. You need to put those all inside one `ViewGroup`, however you need them arranged, and put that `ViewGroup` before the `<NavigationView>`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. A `<NavigationView>` will scroll on its own if the menu is tall enough. Make sure it's listed last in the `<DrawerLayout>`, though, otherwise the content can interfere with touch events.